# How can I extract 'Memory Use Statistics' from ST03N?

Tags: abap, sap-basis

I want to select following data from `ST03N` in a report:

[image]

[image]

After a performance trace, I noticed that the data might be stored in one of the tables:

1. `MONI`
2. `SWNCMONI`

I do not exactly know how to extract the `CLUSTD` data from the table.

I heard of using function module: `SWNC_COLLECTOR_GET_AGGREGATES` , but the data does not exactly match with the data from `ST03N`.

Comment: I found how to extract SWNCMONI-CLUSTD with a example from Class CL_SWNC_AGG_CLUSTER , Method GET_AGGREGATES but the extracted data does not seem to match the ST03N - 'Memory Use Statistics' Data

Answer (score 2):

As one probably knows, the MONI and the newer SWNCMONI database tables are cluster tables and shouldn't be read directly, use new FM `SWNC_COLLECTOR_GET_AGGREGATES` for that.

Nevertheless, if you still want this:

```
TYPES: tt_memory  TYPE TABLE OF swncaggmemory.
DATA:  ms_monikey TYPE swncmonikey,
       dummy      TYPE tt_memory.
FIELD-SYMBOLS:  <tab> TYPE ANY TABLE.

ASSIGN dummy TO <tab>.

ms_monikey-component = <instance_id>.
ms_monikey-comptype = 'NW Workload'.
ms_monikey-assigndsys = <host>.
ms_monikey-periodtype = 'D'.
ms_monikey-periodstrt = '20200713'.

IMPORT datatable TO <tab>
  FROM DATABASE swncmoni(wj) ID ms_monikey
  IGNORING STRUCTURE BOUNDARIES.
```

[image]

As you can see that data for PFCG differs from ST03n in spite it is called for the same date.

Answering on your second question: why it differ?

It may depends on data aggregation setting for memory profile

[image]

also try to play with aggregation period. Actually I also wasn't able to find correspondence between them.

Many useful info about ST03 is here

https://blogs.sap.com/2007/03/16/how-to-read-st03n-datasets-from-db/

Comment: I tested with all Area codes and with different aggregation periods but I still did not get the result from ST03N. It seems that I must debug ST03N and see how the data is being processed after extraction in order to get to that form. It is going to be a fun ride :)

Comment: report about the results of your ride ;) it will be interesting to know the reason of inconsistency